# How do you diagnose which field/method caused a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javaagents

Let's say you have Java code that looks like:

```
getPerson().getParent().getSiblings().first().getName()
```

And you get a NullPointerException on that line. How do you figure out which one was null? You can debug it and check every call, or you can temporarily split the chaining in to multiple lines.

However, I remember seeing an open source project a while ago which would run, I think as a javaagent, which would give you a better stack trace for a NullPointerException where it gave the method call that returned the null result. Unfortunately I can't seem to find it. Does anyone know how that would be done, or what tool it was?

Comment: @Moonbeam from the stack trace he will not know which method caused it since its by line.

Comment: The stack trace shows, eg "SomeFile.java:11" where line 11 is the line above. The question is how do you know whether getPerson() returned null, or getParent() returned null, etc

Comment: I debug the application, set a breakpoint, and check what's null.

Comment: Also, I would recommend you considering using some EL engine, or   [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/) - Uilities for manipulating Java Beans using the XPath syntax.

Comment: @Ondra, if you were to do that don't you lose static type checking and refactoring?

Comment: You can add to existing code check if method returns null with AspectJ and load-time veave (using javaagent). Then throws e.g. IllegalStateException with verbose message. I think this was the tool you mentioned. Look at example in my answer.

Comment: @John Smith is NPE handling that hard for you? I don't mean to come off as rude but there are so many other problems to be solved then taking a few seconds off finding where the NPE is. Particularly since there are so many ways you could write the code for this not to happen. It seems your over-engineering the problem.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is a better style when you don't put in one line methods which may throw npe. Then you don't have such a problem :) Even putting each invocation in a single line (but the same instruction like method1()\n.method2() and so one) is not a good idea. Simple code reformatting can put them back in one line.

If method may return null you should really check the return value each time. If the method should not return null, the getter should contain a check and throw an exception (IllegalStateException?) instead of returning null.

**You can add to existing code such a check with AspectJ and load-time veave (using javaagent).**

For example:

```
/** Throw Error if a method for creating a Point returns null */
after () returning (Point p) : 
    call(Point+ SubPoint+.create(..)) {
    if (null == p) {
        String err = "Null Point constructed when this (" 
            + thisJoinPoint.getThis() 
            + ") called target (" 
            + thisJoinPoint.getTarget() 
            + ") at join point (" 
            + thisJoinPoint.getSignature() 
            + ") from source location (" 
            + thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation()
            + ") with args ("
            + Arrays.asList(thisJoinPoint.getArgs())
            + ")";
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work, but sometimes you don't think something will ever return null, but it does.

Comment: You can add to existing code check if method returns null with AspectJ and load-time veave (using javaagent). Then throws e.g. IllegalStateException with verbose message.

Comment: If you are going to use AspectJ and have that overhead just for NPE why wouldn't you just use JSR 303 validation on your object graph. See my answer.

Comment: @Adam Gent: adding annotations usually implies compilation and code changes. With AspectJ you can add this at load-time.

Comment: @zacheusz and lots of overhead and making the stacktrace look weird (I prefer compile time weaving). I feel like I'm eating crazy pills... when did finding and fixing NPE become so difficult that it requires slower and exotic methods. If its that much of a problem why not switch to Scala or Groovy which offer better null handling support. Or just put each method on its own line.

Comment: @Adam Gent: you are absolutely right (I prefer compile time weaving too and don't use AspectJ to detect NPE). But it looks like that OP has some ready code with NPEs :] In the case when you have lots of compiled code written through many years it might be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.

Can a Person have a null Parent?  (Don't sexually reproducing beings have two Parents?)

What if you're an only child?  What should getSiblings() return?  null or, better yet, an empty Collection?

What if you don't have a first name?  Is Sting or Madonna a first or last name?  If first, what does last name return?

The real issue here is design.  You haven't thought enough about what to do in the case of nulls.  Better to figure that out.

Comment: I made that example up right now, the point is when you have several methods chained together and one of them returned null. Ideally your design doesn't have issues with nulls (like you said, return an empty collection rather than null). Imagine you're debugging legacy code and you come across this issue.

Comment: @duffymo sometimes people are just trying to get stuff done and don't have time be purist. Sometimes you have POJO objects that are deserialized from somewhere and you expect them not to have null values (ie hibernate).

Comment: @Adam, in which case the code isn't expect to care which one is null.

Comment: @Peter Lawry if he cares which one is null I think he should use a JSR 303 POJO validation.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have each method's return value assigned to a variable, so you could just inspect those; that's what the compiler does with temp variables internally anyway.

If you don't feel like re-writing, you can set a breakpoint on that line, and then either add a watch for each function (easiest), or (if your IDE supports it) type each function one-at-a-time into the "immediate" window and see what comes back.

Comment: That would work, but I could have sworn that I saw a tool where you run your application with -javaagent:sometool.jar and it automatically changes your stack trace for a NPE to show the method that returned null, which is even easier than setting a breakpoint and checking each path of the chain in a debugger

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that this is a question of succinct code over maintainable code. Chaining functions may make the code look cleaner, but can lead to a codebase that is harder to maintain over the long haul.  If you separate out your operations, you may have a longer function, but it should be significantly easier to trace down bugs.

Comment: I like chaining.  Fluent interfaces are the bomb.

Answer (score 0):

I think some might be making this far more complicated than what the OP is asking for

All you have to do is put each chained method on its own line.

```
getPerson()
.getParent()
.getSiblings()
.first()
.getName();
```

And you will get the right line number which will indicate which method the NPE is (the previous line is returning null).

And yes you could do all kinds of robust NPE checking but at the end of the day sometimes you need to just get stuff done and null maybe not expected so don't sugar coat it with some other error handling.

**You can also prevent this from happening by adding [validation annotations](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) on the object and its children.** Validate the object and then proceed to walk the object tree. This has worked well for me in the past. This will give you better automatic reusable error handling. Plus you are documenting which methods can return null.

Saying its bad design to support chaining I don't think is fair since one of the most popular Javascript (jQuery) libraries uses it all the time (and yes it returns null/undefined values sometimes).

Comment: It is a good idea. Validation annotations might be very useful, but you have to review existing code and add them to it.

Comment: @zacheusz I didn't even think of the possibility that the OP might be working with old code so excellent point!